# Convert columns names and their values in NA columns

Tags: r, dataframe, converters

I stuck with the following problem:

My dataset (rv):

```
id    group    cat     value     suppl        thera 

1     vita      NA      NA       vita20       0.557

2     vitb      NA      NA       vitb200      0.764

3     vitc      NA      NA        vitc50      0.351
```

**And I expect:**

```
id group cat value

1 vita suppl vita20

1 vita thera 0.557

2  vitb suppl vitb200 

2 vitb thera 0.764

3 vitc suppl vitc50

3 vitc thera 0.351
```

Thank you in advance for your help and time!

Comment: please share code for your data. use `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

With base R `reshape()` you can do this to convert your "wide" data to "long"

```r
x <- read.table(
  header = TRUE,
  text = 
    "id group cat value suppl thera
      1  vita  NA  NA  vita20 0.557
      2  vitb  NA  NA vitb200 0.764
      3  vitc  NA  NA  vitc50 0.351"
)

reshape(
  x,
  idvar = "id",
  timevar = "cat",
  varying = 5:6,
  v.names = "value",
  times = c("suppl", "thera"),
  direction = "long"
)
#>         id group   cat   value
#> 1.suppl  1  vita suppl  vita20
#> 2.suppl  2  vitb suppl vitb200
#> 3.suppl  3  vitc suppl  vitc50
#> 1.thera  1  vita thera   0.557
#> 2.thera  2  vitb thera   0.764
#> 3.thera  3  vitc thera   0.351
```